# what is the command in latex to get the row number?

Tags: latex

As shown in the picture, this row number is not the line number...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These *row* numbers are most likely inserted after the fact using some form of overlay, since the numbers don't line up with the vertical line spread of the actual document.

You can do this by overlaying a stack of numbers in the `F`ore`G`round via [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,eso-pic,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\linenobox}
\let\tbnl\relax
% Construct the "row" numbers
\savebox{\linenobox}{%
  \color{black!50}% Colour of numbers
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \def\xx{\unskip}%
    \multido{\i=1+1}{70}{\xdef\xx{\xx\ifnum\i<10 0\fi0\i\tbnl}}% Construct stack
    \global\let\tbnl\\
    \xx% Set stack
  \end{tabular}
}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{\usebox{\linenobox}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```